# Building app -- need info on viewing other users playlists

Tags: playlist

I am currently building an app and would like the option of having users view other users playlists. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this is possible. All this data would be in a database, and you would write stored procedures that would fall in a REST API that you would call from your app. You would need to do the filtering of said stored procedure to show users any kind of data you want (if you only want to show 'friends' playlists, or 'people around you'..etc). Remember, it's just all data. Nothing more. You format the data to look nice, but it's still just data.

Comment: Thank you Omeed. Another question... would it be possible to display the data (playlist) without closing my app and opening spotify?

Comment: Yes this data would be fetched from a REST API and you would display the data however you want.